# How to Update Cordova version in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

I recently imported my project over from Eclipse over to Android Studio. I created a gradle as well and everything runs fine. However, I'd like to update my Cordova version because Google Developer Console says my current version is deprecated. I've tried to navigate through `CordovaActivity.java` and other files to actually find out my version but for some reason it's not visible in Android Studio, but in Eclipse it was definitely visible in the .xml files. I even checked the new gradle files. There is actually no mention of how to update in the documentation for Cordova/Android on google either.

So my question is how do I actually update cordova in Android Studio?

Below is my CordovaLib build.gradle file. It says buildToolsVersion 23.0.2 but that can't be right, I believe 5.4.0 is the latest Cordova version. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**to update cordova:**

1. open a console and type: `cordova -v` -> current version is displayed
2. type `npm update -g cordova`

**to update cordova in your project:**

3. Go to your project folder
4. type `cordova platform update android` (or your type of platform)

See the documentation of cordova CLI [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/cli/).

Comment: Thanks for this. For some reason, it keeps saying my project isn't a cordova-based project. I recently imported over to Android Studio so it built a gradle for me. http://imgur.com/a/mvk09 Am I technically entering `cordova platform update android` incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I think u should try netbeans for your project development that helps a lot in updating cordova and plugin using npm cmd to install and update..